# T-SQL error with STUFF((SELECT......)) function in SQL Server CE

Tags: t-sql

Using SQL Server CE in Visual Studio 2008, I try to query a database like this:

```
select          
   [INTESTAZIONE Ente], 
   [INTESTAZIONE Tipo],
   [INTESTAZIONE Anno], 
   [INTESTAZIONE Protocollo], 
   COUNT([Mittenti Mittente]) AS [N.MITTENTI],
   [Mittenti Mittente] AS [MITTENTI],
   STUFF(
           (SELECT ',' + [Mittenti Mittente] AS [ELENCO MITTENTI]
            FROM ElencoMittenti
            WHERE [ElencoMittenti.[Mittenti  Mittente]] = [Elenco_Ricorsi.[Mittenti Mittente]]
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS [RISULTATO]
from    
   Elenco_Ricorsi
group by 
   [INTESTAZIONE Ente], [INTESTAZIONE Tipo],[INTESTAZIONE Anno], 
   [INTESTAZIONE Protocollo], [Mittenti Mittente]
```

I need the `STUFF((SELECT.....)` command to build an array a result of this query.

This query gives an error:

> *token in error = SELECT" and the problem comes from the nested
>   'select'*

I have read this is possible to do also with SQL Server Compact Edition, so I think I have made some error in query.

Comment: does your inner query run individually?

Comment: of course, if i cancel the stuff() instruction, the rest of the query works.

Comment: Is the XML data type supported in CE? It is not stuff that does the concatenation it is building XML using `for xml path`.

Comment: According to what is written here: [link] http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/ac926272-2382-4acb-84e3-fc32945c7cea [/link] it seems that SQL COMPACT 3.5 doesn't support the nested select.

Answer (score 2):

your brackets are just in the wrong place when referencing a table you need to wrap the square brackets around the [tablename].[columnname], I have included a modified version that should work:

```
        SELECT  [INTESTAZIONE Ente] ,
        [INTESTAZIONE Tipo] ,
        [INTESTAZIONE Anno] ,
        [INTESTAZIONE Protocollo] ,
        COUNT([Mittenti Mittente]) AS [N.MITTENTI] ,
        [Mittenti Mittente] AS [MITTENTI] ,
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + [Mittenti Mittente] AS [ELENCO MITTENTI]
                FROM    ElencoMittenti
                WHERE   [ElencoMittenti].[Mittenti  Mittente] = [Elenco_Ricorsi].[Mittenti Mittente]
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '') AS [RISULTATO]
FROM    Elenco_Ricorsi
GROUP BY [INTESTAZIONE Ente] ,
        [INTESTAZIONE Tipo] ,
        [INTESTAZIONE Anno] ,
        [INTESTAZIONE Protocollo] ,
        [Mittenti Mittente]
```